# validation of e-mail

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

How can I do the opposite of the following code.
I need to check if it's false at the first place not if it's right.

```
var a = $("#phone").val();
var filter = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

if(filter.test(a)) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: In general forget it to validate email adresses with regular expressions. There are so called umlaut domains where a domain can contain almost every charector. E.g. hällo@füße.de would be a valid mail adress.

Comment: Add ! (bang) before filter.test(a)? :D
I would rather find out how some frameworks do email validation and use it.

Comment: Exchange the `then` and `else` branches?:)

Comment: But there is sure an RFC in which E-Mail-Adresses are specified. If you form the RegEx after the Spec every valid E-Mail is covered. And RegEx knows [^@].

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question!?

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong it is phone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put ! before `filter.test(a)` or use `filter.test(a) == false`

```
var a = $("#phone").val();
var filter = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

if(!filter.test(a)) { // or if(filter.test(a) == false)

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if(filter.test(a))
```

to

```
if(!filter.test(a))
```

the ! will negate the bool

Answer (score 0):

You already have one way using the `if` statement as it stands if you need to run 2 versions of code

```
if(filter.test(a)) {
  /* run code if true*/
} else {
  /* run code if false*/
}
```

To reverse the `if` test simply add exclamation mark

```
if( !filter.test(a)) {
 /* run code if false*/
}
```